# Does regularity of a D-module for an unusual filtration imply regularity for the usual one?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, differential-operators, d-modules

One definition of regular D-modules on affine space is that a D-module is **regular** if it has a filtration compatible with the order filtration on differential operators whose associated graded is reduced as a coherent sheaf, that is, its annihilator is a radical ideal.

But, differential operators on affine space have a lot of filtrations.  For example, if I look at $\mathbb{A}^n$ and choose $n$ positive integers $a_i$, I can define a filtration of the following form: we let $x_i$ lie in $D^{-a_i}$ and $\partial_i$ in $D^{1+a_i}$ and extend the filtration to the rest of the differential operators in the obvious way.  Not all D-modules have good filtrations with respect to this filtration, but some do (for example, any homogeneous with respect to the action of $\mathbb{C}^*$ with weights $a_i$).

> Does the condition of having a filtration compatible with this one whose associated graded is reduced as a coherent sheaf, that is, its annihilator is a radical ideal have an interesting consequences?  Most importantly, does it imply regularity in the usual sense given above?
>
> For that matter, has this filtration been studied by anyone?  Is there any literature on it?

I'll note, if I let the $a_i$'s be negative, regularity definitely isn't preserved by this change of filtration: there are regular D-modules whose Fourier transforms aren't regular.

Comment: Ben, I am confused about your definition of regularity.
If you take the D-module generated by $e^x$ on ${\mathbb A}^1$ it obviously has a filtration such that the associated graded is the structure sheaf of the zero section in the cotangent bundle and it is not
regular. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean that the $D$-module is regular on ${\mathbb A}^n$ without
infinity? In this case I would be interested to see the proof of your original statement. In any case if you take your $D$-module to 
be $exp(1/x)$ on ${\mathbb A}^1$ and set $deg(x)=-1$ and $deg(d)=2$
then you can define a filtration $M_i$ to be generated over functions by all $p(x)exp(1/x)$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial in $x^{-1}$ of degree $\leq i$ and I think it gives a counterexample.